# Опечатка в описании привилегии

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, справка

В [описании привилегии "Правка Вопросов И Ответов"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) в последнем абзаце неправильный линк на `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits"`, должен быть `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits`, без кавычки.

Забавно, что я не могу вносить правки в ту страницу :) Хотя в тексте указано, что, цитирую,

> *мы доверяем вам право редактировать в системе все, что угодно*.

Comment: *не могу вносить правки в ту страницу* — эта страница — шаблон, заполняемый локализованными строками. локализация проходит на trasifex-е. если интересуют подробности, поищите здесь соответствующие ключевые слова.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Немного уточню. Разделы справочного центра (описание привилегий один из таких разделов) переведены во внутреннем механизме движка, то есть, к сожалению, их нет на Transifex. Вносить изменения могут либо сотрудники компании, либо модераторы. Чтобы модератор мог изменять текст такой публикации,  необходимо выставить специальную настройку в админке сайта. Одновременно нельзя выставить флаг на изменения более чем двум статьям.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, спасибо за уточнение. я правильно понимаю, что после снятия упомянутого флага (например, для перестановки его на другой раздел справки) все изменения, сделанные модератором, пропадут?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Нет, все изменения будут сохранены. Система просто не дает править все публикации одновременно (максимум две).

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо за замечание, исправили.